# Matrix regularization, how to pick $\lambda$

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, linear-algebra

[Since v12](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn120.html) `FindFit[]` now supports regularisation, such as  Tikhonov regularization. Do there exist statistics to help guide the choice of the hyper-parameter $\lambda$ implemented in Mathematica?

For example, popular choices are the Generalized Cross-Validation (GCV) [statistic](https://doi.org/10.1080/00401706.1979.10489751) or the $C_P$ [statistic](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2012.10.005) - both of which seem widely used in other languages.

Are there optimized functions for these statistics?

Comment: Similiar question: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Feb/msg00245.html